# Does the Scythe Gate drain mana when banishing monsters?

Tags: gemcraft-chasing-shadows

Field H1 has a Scythe gate that will randomly banish monsters that pass through it. When monsters reach your orb they will be banished with some mana cost; is that the case here, too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've played this level and watched my mana carefully. The answer is 'No'.

I'm not sure what happens if the monsters are carrying orblets.